# File IO not happenieng inside a Pthread, c++ application

Tags: c++, multithreading, file-io, gdb

I am using CentOS 6.3 64 bit and trying to develop a c++ application using IBM® Data Studio
Version 4.1.0.1 which is a flavor of eclipse. I have written a multithread application and all was going well till I tried to do file IO. 
I used ofstream to write my data to a file . But this is not allowing me to debug this snippet of code, If I place any breakpoints it shows a break point can not be placed .

I have written this piece of code in a thread **(pthread)**

```
ofstream myfile;
char chFileName[100];
sprintf(chFileName,"Json_%s_%s_%d",strType,strGroupID,iIndex);
myfile.open (chFileName);
myfile << strJSON;
myfile.close();
```

Here is the console output before the application and thread terminates.

> [Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled] [New Thread 0x7fffe9f1e700 (LWP 28380)] [New Thread 0x7fffe951d700 (LWP 28381)]
>   [Switching to Thread 0x7fffe951d700 (LWP 28381)] [Thread 0x7fffe951d700 (LWP 28381) exited] [Thread 0x7fffe9f1e700 (LWP 28380)
>   exited]

Is it not wise to perform file IO in a thread ?
Could someone please help me with how to fix this issue ?

Comment: What about your main thread, is it still running?

Comment: Have you build with debug information?

Comment: Yes the main thread is still running , and I do not know how to enable it. Can you please tell me where to find that info on eclipse ?

Comment: Does the file exist in the current working directory? Did it even open successfully? You never check so for all you know your writing to a stream that is ignoring all your efforts. A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would go a long way to determining what the problem is, because I assure you file IO, including from spawned threads, works correctly if properly configured.

Comment: I am creating a new file with the parameters which keep changing and if I run this piece of code in my main () function I could see the file created in my working directory.

Comment: I really don't see any reason why ofestream (or any other file access) shouldn't work in a pthread. You may of course want to checkk that the file was created correctly.... And that the filename is correct (e.g. if you are passing strType and strGroupID in a way that they are no longer present in the creation callframe, you could end up with "garbage", and that could lead to an invalid filename.

Comment: No the problem is I can not even place a breakpoint in the function, when breakpoint hits the first line, debugging stops . I can't procede and the execution halts after few seconds. As I said it works fine in main() function.